# Enviando um objeto através de Session

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte o objeto

```
$compra = new Compra($usuario, $produto_comprado, $cep['cep'], $soma_produtos);
```

Quando tento adiciona-lo em um `$_SESSION[]` e tento pega-lo em outra página, ele me retorna ele me retorna `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` em um var_dump();

No atributo `$produto_comprado` eu tento inserir uma array da seguinte forma:

```
$produtos = $lista->listaProdutos($conexao, $usuario);

$produto_comprado = array();
foreach ($produtos as $row) {
    array_push($produto_comprado, $produto);
}
```

Minha classe compra:

```
class Compra
{
    private $usuario;
    private $produto_comprado;
    private $cep;
    private $modo_pagamento;
    private $total;

    public function __construct($usuario, $produto_comprado, $cep, $total)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->produto_comprado = $produto_comprado;
        $this->cep = $cep;
        $this->total = $total;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $usuario
     */
    public function setUsuario($usuario)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProdutoComprado()
    {
        return $this->produto_comprado;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $produto_comprado
     */
    public function setProdutoComprado($produto_comprado)
    {
        $this->produto_comprado = $produto_comprado;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCep()
    {
        return $this->cep;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $cep
     */
    public function setCep($cep)
    {
        $this->cep = $cep;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getModoPagamento()
    {
        return $this->modo_pagamento;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $modo_pagamento
     */
    public function setModoPagamento($modo_pagamento)
    {
        $this->modo_pagamento = $modo_pagamento;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $total
     */
    public function setTotal($total)
    {
        $this->total = $total;
    }




}
```

Existe uma maneira melhor de eu enviar os dados deste objeto para um outra página?

Comment: Aparentemente ha alguma coisa em seu objeto que precisa ser reconstruído. De um var_dump nele pra ver o que ele tem.

Comment: Alterei a resposta.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Dei var_dump() e ele me traz todos os valores....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialize o objeto assim:

```
session_start(); // isso tem que ficar como primeira linha do codigo
$compra = new Compra($usuario, $produto_comprado, $cep['cep'], $soma_produtos);
$_SESSION['compra'] = serialize($compra);
```

Depois, para voltar ao normal, basta recuperar desta forma:

```
session_start();
require_once(SuaClasseCompra.php);
$compra = unserialize($_SESSION['compra']);
```

**Referencias:**

[Documentação php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/oop4.serialization.php)

[Serialização de objetos em SESSION no PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/serializacao-de-objetos-em-session-no-php/28535)

[SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925447/5524514)

Comment: A saída é a mesma, @DiegoFelipe....  http://i.imgur.com/oERoTM9.png

Comment: @Naldson adicione mais código a sua pergunta, como a classe Compra e o trecho mais amplo do código que transfere o objeto entre sessoes, talvez o problema nao seja bem ai.

Comment: De certo!! Faltou mesmo só o requerer a classe Compras onde eu pegava a sessão... Muito obrigado! ;)

Comment: Mas, @DiegoFelipe...Quando dou var_dump em $copra->getProdutoComprado() ele me retorna __PHP_Incomplete_Class de novo... diferente dos outros dados....

Comment: @Naldson faça o require_once da sua classe compra no começo de todo script php que você precisar manipular essa classe. O problema de aparecer essa classe é por não conhecer a definição da classe compra.