# Há a possibilidade de manter um objeto em uma variável de sessão?

Tags: php, session

Eu crio a variável:

`$Client = new SoapClient(...);`

E depois:

`$_SESSION["Cliente"] = $Client;`

Para não ter que fazer uma requisição completa a cada página.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Nunca tentei, mas provavelmente sim, não vi necessidade da pergunta, pois era só você ter estado que teria respondido sua dúvida. Dependendo da classe, seria melhor transforma-la em estática.

Comment: Trabalhando com Chat em TCP/IP as vezes temos necessidade de manter uma conexao persistente, no meu caso faço uma conexão num Webservice e gostaria de saber se há como manter essa conexão enquanto o usuario estiver na area restrita, assim quando ele mudar de pagina não preciso ficar refazendo a conexão mas somente executaria as funções pra obter retorno. Eu fiz o teste e não consegui, mas talvez tenha uma modo de fazer, por isso minha pergunta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviando um objeto através de Session](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98268/70)

Answer (score 3):

Sim é possível.

Inclusive você não precisa usar nenhuma função adicional.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

**CLASSE PESSOA**

```
<?php 
class Pessoa{
    public $name;
    public $idade;

    function count(){
        echo '123456';
    }
}?>
```

**VIEW/CONTROLLER**

```
    <?php 
        include("Pessoa.php");
        $pessoa = new Pessoa;
        $pessoa->nome = 'Ricardo';
        $pessoa->idade = 22;

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['pessoa'] = $pessoa;

        $_SESSION["pessoa"]->count();

        session_destroy();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para a tua situação acredito que deves repensar a maneira como está sendo desenvolvido teu projeto, mas respondendo a tua pergunta:

Sim, há a possibilidade de manter um objeto salvo. Dê uma lida sobre o método [serialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php), ele retorna uma `string` com os dados representados no objeto. Para tornar a string em um objeto, utiliza-se o método [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php).

Exemplificando:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->hello = 'Hello world';

var_dump($object);

/*
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["hello"]=>
  string(11) "Hello world"
}
*/

var_dump(serialize($object));
/*
string(50) "O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"hello";s:11:"Hello world";}"
*/
```

Dessa forma, você pode salvar na sessão o objeto serializado:

```
$_SESSION["serializedObject"] = serialize($object);
```

E resgatá-lo:

```
$sessionObject = unserialize($_SESSION["serializedObject"]);
```

Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/m63OQ1)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, fiz isso faz algum tempo e no momento não tenho como testar, se não me engano você deve utilizar as funções [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) e [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Ao atribuir a superglobal:

```
$_SESSION['Cliente'] = serialize($client)
```

Para atribuir da superglobal para uma outra variável:

```
$var_destino = unserialize($_SESSION['Cliente'])
```